# Does Cyanogenmod Kernel support loop devices?

Tags: cyanogenmod, kernel, mount, loopback

Since I am failing to mount a Nandroid image and since I have read that the kernel needs to support loop devices for that I need to know if anybody has managed to mount a loop device on CM7 or similar. Any information on mounting loop devices in Cyanogenmod or other Mods are highly appreciated.

[Cross-posted to the Cyanogenmod forum](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/26569-does-cyanogendmod-kernel-support-loop-devices/page__p__214348__hl__r3s3t__fromsearch__1#entry214348)

Comment: I've heard other reports of CM's kernel not supporting loopback devices.  I know the syntax can be slightly different from the standard Linux mount, so I would check to make sure you're using it [like this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5218/can-i-mount-loopdevice-in-android/5219#5219).  If you want help finding a kernel, please post your device make/model.

Comment: Oh, and you might try [busybox mount](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10696/mount-on-2-3-4-is-behaving-oddly/10710#10710) as well.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions with no success. I would like to try a custom kernel if it is not too difficult. I am using a HTC Desire (Bravo PVT4).

Answer (score 1):

According to zivmo on the linked thread, Cyanogenmod 7.1 stable and later ship with loop support built into the kernel, so loop devices just work without having to compile or insert a kernel module.